# How do I convert a dataframe consisting of a column of sentences and a column of scores into one with a column of words and average scores?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a Pandas dataframe that resembles this:

```
sentence              score
"This is a sentence." 5
"Another sentence?"   8
```

And I want one that resembles this:

```
word       total_score  count  normalized_score
"sentence" 13           2      6.5
"this"     5            1      5
```

etc.

How should I go about doing this? My thought is to remove all non-alphanumeric characters, then use [split()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) on all of the cells containing sentences, then combine those words into a set, then use that set to iterate through the original dataframe, counting the number of times a word is used and the corresponding scores. This, however, seems inelegant and potentially incredibly inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Note: Don't worry about stop words and assume all words are separated by spaces

Edit:

The head of the actual data (after applying `wide = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['score'], index=x['sentence']), axis=1)` ) is:

```
   score                                                                      title
0      1                           [javascript, kml, compressor, for, google, maps]
1      3             [ktbyte, challenge, programming, game, for, 9, 15, year, olds]
2      4                              [worldometers, real, time, world, statistics]
3      1                                                [apple, s, sales, policies]
4     72                  [report, suggests, 21, hours, is, the, ideal, work, week]
5      3  [new, paper, shows, how, to, get, control, without, injecting, new, code]
```

Strangely, unutbu's solution works for the first 5 rows, but not when the sixth is added. When the sixth is added, Python returns `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` (which seems to be Panda's vaguely defined catch-all error for reindexing).

Comment: In the sixth row `'new'` appears twice. Does it still get a score of 3 as though it only appeared once? Or should it get a score of 6? (Handling these duplicates will resolve the "cannot reindex" ValueError.)

Comment: Does the `count` column count the number of times each word appears, or does it count the number of *rows* in which the word appears?

Comment: It should get a score of 6, although I'd be interested to know what the solution for it getting a score of 3 would be as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `df.itertuples` to iterate through the rows of `df` and build a
long-format DataFrame of the form:

```
In [86]: longframe
Out[86]: 
   score      word
0      5      This
1      5        is
2      5         a
3      5  sentence
4      8   Another
5      8  sentence
6      8  sentence
```

Once you have the data in this format, you could group by `word` and sum the scores for each word, and use `value_counts` to count the frequency of each word.

---

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'score': [5, 8], 'sentence': ["This is a sentence.", "Another sentence sentence?"]})
df['sentence'] = df['sentence'].str.findall(r'\w+')

longframe = pd.DataFrame([(row.score, word) for row in df.itertuples() 
                          for word in row.sentence], 
                         columns=['score', 'word'])
score = longframe.groupby('word')['score'].sum()
count = longframe['word'].value_counts()
result = pd.DataFrame({'score':score, 'count':count, 'normalized_score':score/count})
result = result.reset_index()
result = result.rename(columns={'index':'word'})
print(result)
```

yields

```
       word  count  normalized_score  score
0   Another      1               8.0      8
1      This      1               5.0      5
2         a      1               5.0      5
3        is      1               5.0      5
4  sentence      3               7.0     21
```

Comment: Is there a non-iterative way to do this?

Comment: I don't know a better way. There is a new vectorized str method, [`extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#addition-of-str-extractall) which avoids the intermediate column of lists created by `df['sentence'].str.findall(r'\w+')`. This holds out the possibility of a faster, non-Python-loop-based solution. Unfortunately, currently `extractall` uses Python loops [under the hood](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/strings.py#L704) so there is no performance advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `iterrows` method on the DataFrame to and process each row into a new DataFrame and then concatenate these together.  You would then need to handle duplicate words.

The `string` module (in the standard library) has some collections of characters that can help you filter out the non-alphanumeric vales.